# Property of an AppModel application not getting updated in SCCM

Tags: c#, sccm

I'm trying to update `SDMPackageXML` property of an AppModel application through C# code. `SDMPackageXML` is an XML property. I've to update only one node named `AutoInstall` in the 
`SDMPackageXML` XML property. Here is my code:

```
                ObjectGetOptions opt = new ObjectGetOptions(null, System.TimeSpan.MaxValue, true);
                var path = new ManagementPath("SMS_Application.CI_ID=16777568");
                ManagementObject obj = new ManagementObject(scope, path, opt);
                obj.Get();
                foreach (PropertyData property in obj.Properties)
                {
                    if (property.Name == "SDMPackageXML")
                    {
                        //change the property value. Set AutoInstall to true
                        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

                        xml.LoadXml(property.Value.ToString());
                        var autoInstallTag = xml.GetElementsByTagName("AutoInstall");
                        autoInstallTag[0].InnerText = "false";
                        property.Value = xml.OuterXml;
                    }
                }
                obj.Put();
```

The problem is that `obj.Put();` updates nothing on the SCCM server. Can someone help me please?

Comment: This is probably the same root problem I talked about in the other topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61366689/sms-application-wmi-classs-equivalent-table-in-sccm-database). You need Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.dll and its De/SerializeToString methods if you want to manipulate that xml part. Do you want me to formulate an answer in c# for that kind of solution or is your problem that you cannot use that dll?

Comment: Yes. Kindly formulate an answer using de/serialised method in C#. I'm ready to reference that DLL

Answer (score 0):

So similar to what I talked about [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61366689/sms-application-wmi-classs-equivalent-table-in-sccm-database) the main problem here is that Microsoft uses a special method to serialize their XML. The deserialization still works with using the default classes but to serialize again there is no documentation as to how to (I'm pretty sure it is possible but I am not knowledgeable enough to do it)
Instead of documentation they provide wrapper classes for this which are shipped with the SCCM Console (Located in the bin directory of the Installation folder of the Console).

In this case this would be Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.dll. Unlike in powershell where the dependencies in the same path seem to be loaded as well you seem also to have to reference at least Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.TaskSequenceInstaller.dll as well.

There are also further dlls with names like Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.MsiInstaller.dll present however at least in my tests the two above were the only ones needed, but if you notice the deserialization failing with "InvalidPropertyException" errors you might need the dll matching your specific application type.

With those two dlls referenced you can write something like this (note I deserialized using the dll as well because why not if it is already loaded and it creates a nice application object to directly modify the properties. This is however technically not necessary. You could deserialize like in your example and only use the serialization part.

```
ManagementObject obj = new ManagementObject(@"\\<siteserver>\root\SMS\site_<sitecode>:SMS_Application.CI_ID=<id>");
Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Application app = Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Serialization.SccmSerializer.DeserializeFromString(obj["SDMPackageXML"].ToString(), true);
app.AutoInstall = true;
obj["SDMPackageXML"] = Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Serialization.SccmSerializer.SerializeToString(app, true);
obj.Put();
```

Now one thing to keep in mind is that is can be a little tricky referencing the applications by their CI_ID because if you update the application the id for the currently valid version of the app changes (the old id still can be used to reference the older revision). So if you change the application gotten using the ID and then change it back with the same ID it will look like only the first change worked. I don't know if this is problematic for you (If you just get all IDs then change every application only once it should not matter) but if it does you can search for the application using their name plus `isLatest = 'true'` in the WQL query to always get the current one.

Comment: Those are quite annoying to debug because you get so little information. It could happen if you assign something other than the direct output of SerializeToString to obj["SDMPackageXML"] (if you use your original variant I think it would be assigned to  property.Value but I am not sure). Did you change any other value of the ManagementObject?